# Detecting login - SQLMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, authentication, sqlmembershipprovider

I'm using ASP.Net MVC Authentication, SqlMembershipProvider to be specific.

I have a website that has multiple login forms across the site. Some of which do not have controllers that I am exposed to (as the login pages are part of closed source CMS).

I'm trying to create a record of user login history - and in order to do this, I need to hook into some kind of event which ideally is fired globally when a user logs into the SqlMembershipProvider.

Does anyone know if there is a global C# event that I can use to detect when a user logs into their account?

Thanks

Comment: I hope it is easier than this, but an option would be to write a trigger for the user table when last activity date is changed that will log what you need.

Comment: Indeed, I had this thought too. Although not ideal!